# Best way to query Repeating Events With available seat

Tags: django, icalendar, recurrence, python-dateutil, rfc5545

I have a recurring events application, each event can have multiple recurrence patterns ([RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)), a date can be in different recurrence patterns so I have added an autofield integer to prioritize the most recently added recurrences, each recurrence pattern has a max seat capacity.
So far so good the problem starts when I need to check all the dates that have seats available for the next 365 days:
I would have to check each date against a recurrence rule/pattern and finding that date get the capacity associated with the recurrence.

maybe an example pseudocode is better understood than my English.
ex.:

```
reseved = "info with the number of person by each date reserved"
patterns = {
    0:["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;", "max 10 person"],
    1:["RRULE:FREQ=MONTLY;UNTIL=2021-10-10", "max 15 person"],
    2:["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=2021-06-15", "max 25 person"]
}
patterns_ordered = patterns.order_by["index"]
date = "2021-01-01"
last_date = "2021-01-01" + 365 days
while date < laste_date:
    for rule in patterns_ordered:
        If date in rule and rule.capacity > number_reserved in date:
            save date in array with it's availibility.
```

this is very costly in terms of performance, I have tried to check month after month while the user is browsing a calendar. it is very expensive and the server is overloaded with the number of ajax calls.

more information about my model class:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    e_name = CharField
    e_description = TexField

class EventRecurrence(models.Model):
    event = ForeignKey(to=Event)
    rfc_pattern = CharField #with rfc ical validation
    max_guest = PositiveIntegerField
    index = OrderedPositiveIntegerField # an autofield based in event

clas Reservation(models.Model):
    date = DateField # date reserved
    passengers = PositiveIntegerField
    amount = DecimalField
    event = ForeignKey(to=Event)
    ...........
```

Comment: It would probably be useful to provide your model classes.

Comment: thankyou @sytech I have been updated my question.

Comment: You might consider caching the available days and only recomputing them when they need to change, e.g. when a reservation is made, a rule is changed, number of guests is changed, etc.

Comment: Hello, @AKX I have considered your Approach, but I would like to read different approaches. If I end up implementing it, I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: not sure if it matches your need, but have you reviewed https://django-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html ? It may provide some insights.